# Creating .xsd and .xml with optional element (if - then)

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I need to create xsd and xml files with special characteristics. For example `'Plane'` with `'Model'  ... 'Ammo'`. If I set `'Ammo'` to `true` I need to set the number of `Missiles` (0-10). If `'Ammo'` is set to `false` I should not be able to choose amount of `Missiles`. How can I make this switcher?

Part of sxd file:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Plane">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Model" type="tns:Model" />   
        <xsd:element name="Ammunition" type="xsd:boolean" />
        <!-- If ammo is true add Missiles -->
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Model">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="ModelType" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="Missile">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:byte">
        <xsd:minExclusive value="0" />
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="10" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

And a part of `xml` file:

```
 <Plane>
    <Model>
        <ModelType>MiG-29</ModelType>
    </Model>

    <Ammunition>true</Ammunition>

    <!-- Set amount of missiles -->

 </Plane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSD 1.0 alone cannot express cross field validations. You would need to extend it using Schematron or switch to XSD 1.1, the later still not popular.

To maintain the use of the `Ammunition` tag, I would convert it to a complex type and make it optional; its content would contain your supported ammo, which in effect would achieve the same semantics. Ideallty, I would remove the Ammunition tag alltogether, it is not adding information, just overhead.